# Intellij Idea not showing separate tests of a Suite when using scala test

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest

When running a scala-test suite in Intellij Idea, it's supposed to show the breakup of the individual tests that it ran, as shown in screenshot below, as explained in [scala-test Intellij guide](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_intellij).However when running scala-test in Intellij Idea Community Edition 2019.2, I can't see the breakup of individual tests. Only the aggregated result is shown. How do I fix it to show the individual tests?

[Expected test breakup in IntellijIdea when running scala-test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py0Un.png)

[Actual IntellijIdea output on running scala-test. The individual tests are not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwNhT.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it solves the issue when you enable "Show Passed" option in runner tab?
[image]

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks  a lot